# Given a graphql.js schema, how can I find all the variants of a particular union type?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

Suppose I have a graphQL schema built like this:

```js
var { buildSchema } = require('graphql');

// Construct a schema, using GraphQL schema language
var schema = buildSchema(`
  type Human = // some object type
  type Droid = // another object type
  union SearchResult = Human | Droid
  type Query {
    result: SearchResult
  }
`);

const searchResultVariants = ?
```

Now I am looking for a way to programmatically find out all the variants of `SearchResult` type in the same program for the given `schema`, is there a way for that? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the abstract type (interface or union) in question:

```
const searchResultType = schema.getType('SearchResult');
```

then get its possible types:

```
const possibleTypes = schema.getPossibleTypes(searchResultType);
```

`possibleTypes` will an array of `GraphQLObjectType` objects.

You can also test whether a particular type is a possible type of an abstract type using `isPossibleType`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you please share where these methods are documented?